# Prove that for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|\cos(x-2^n)-1|<\varepsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\varepsilon>0$. I would like to know if there is a natural number $n$ such that $|\cos(x-2^n)-1|<\varepsilon$.

I was trying to prove that there exists $k \in \mathbb{Z}_+$ such that $x-2^n \in \left(2k \pi, (4k+1)\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$, but I couldn't prove it. This would only imply that $0<\cos(x-2^n)<1$. I couldn't find a correct way to solve the problem. Note that I'm not asking for the existence of a natural number $n_0$ such that $|\cos(x-2^n)-1|<\varepsilon$ for all $n \geq n_0$.

Answer (score 1):

Translate into what it means for the argument of $\cos$

$$\|\frac{x - 2^n}{2\pi}\| < \delta$$

where $\|\cdot\|$ denotes the distance from the closest integer.  Or,
$$\frac{x}{2\pi} - 2^n\frac{1}{2 \pi}$$ is very close to an integer, for some $n$.

Let's write everything in base $2$. $x' \colon = \frac{x}{2\pi}$, $\eta= \frac{1}{2 \pi}$. The statement would be that you can guarantee that there always exists a chunk of the binary expansion of $\eta$ of a given form.  For instance, there exists in the binary expansion of $\frac{1}{2\pi}$ a sequence of a trillion $0$'s followed by a trillion $1$'s.  Now, everybody believes that this is true, but we cannot prove it yet.
See  [normal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number).

Comment: In short, I won't be able to prove the above statement so easily, right?

Comment: @Victor Hugo: Yes, that seems very difficult to prove. Note that if instead $2^n$ we have $n$ or a polynomial in $n$, it is not that difficult to show.